# How to access global variables inside groovy class files?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, global-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following directory structure

```
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- Bar.groovy  # for org.foo.Bar class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable
```

And I have the following lines of code in the following files

1. `Bar.groovy`

   ```groovy
   package org.foo

   class Bar implements Serializable {
     def config
     def script

     Bar(script, config){
       this.script = script
       this.config = config
     }

     def accessGlobalVars(){
       this.script.echo "${foo.GlobalVar}" // throws an err
     }
   }
   ```
2. `foo.groovy`

   ```groovy
   import groovy.transform.Field
   @Field GlobalVar="Hello World!"
   ```

I'm able to access the variable in the Jenkinsfile inside the script block

```
echo "${foo.GlobalVar}"
```

Is it possible to access the same variable inside the class since the vars folder is at src folder level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `"${foo.GlobalVar}"` in your example code is trying to resolve the `foo` against the `Bar` type. Since there is no `foo` reference it cannot be resolved and you will probably get something like a `MissingPropertyException`.

Jenkins Pipeline Groovy does some different compilation and binding using the Groovy compilation and runtime APIs. The global variables can also be resolved through the `script` object through its dynamic `GroovyObject` APIs (demonstrated in the source code [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/a63e6848d642b65f21e32ea7d15a8a853de8761a/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.java#L112-L138)). The easiest way is to let the dynamic Groovy object resolution implemented by Jenkins resolve your variable.

Change your line from:

```
this.script.echo "${foo.GlobalVar}"
```

To instead lookup the `foo` from the `script` object (which I am presuming is the `this` or `script` in your Jenkins pipeline by `new Foo(this, config)`):

```
this.script.echo "${this.script.foo.GlobalVar}"
```